# Visual Studio Code intellisense showing one suggestion at any time

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

Normally when I used to type in my VSCode editor, the intellisense showed all the possible suggestions for the entered query.

However, now as I type, only one suggestion is shown that best matches the query.

For instance, when I type in `b`, the intellisense just shows a suggestion for the HTML `<b>` element — not a *list* of suggestions including tags such as `<button>`.

Is there any way to change this? I have searched a lot of the net but couldn't find any sort of help.

Comment: Try changing the size of the suggestion box by dragging your cursor down from the bottom of the box.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!

Answer (score 271, accepted):

VS Code 1.51 [made the list of suggestions resizable](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_resizable-suggestions) so it's possible your suggest widget is simply shrunken down to be a single line high.

To fix this, trigger suggestions and then click and drag at the bottom edge of the suggest widget to increase the number of visible suggestions.

[image: Resizing the suggest widget]

Note that you can always use the arrow keys to navigate through suggestions, even if only one suggestion is visible. Use this to check if the widget is simply too small or if there really is only one suggestion

Comment: Would give 1,000 upvotes if I could. It was so stupid of Microsoft to, by default, limit suggestions to 1 line with no obvious way to make it look the way it used to look before the update.

Comment: This is not the default. In the most recent update, a few users got the suggest widget reset to wrong size due to a bug

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a link to an issue somewhere related to this bug? I guess I should look at where people work before I go throwing words like "stupid" around.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me crazy... Such an unintuitve feature. I feel like this should just be a setting e.g. maxsuggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought my VS Code instances were bugged.  Hope the default/size calculation gets fixed soon.  Can't find the issues to report either.

Comment: Thank you for this. It would be great if the item list showed a resize indicator in the bottom corner, to indicate this is resizable.

Comment: I would love to know where this requirement came from.   100% not a user request or from feedback.  No need

Comment: The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110971

Answer (score 21):

I wasted time on this too... (bummed)

---

Solution:

- Open:   Command Palette
- Type:   ">Reset Suggest Widget Size"
- Select: 'click' or [ENTER]

---

Opinion:

Wish I saw Matt Bierner's answer sooner.
(The suggestion window can be resized by dragging its borders with your cursor.)