# why my emmet abbreviation only show 2 column?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

yesterday my emmet abbreviation was able to show a lot but now only 2, how can I fix it?

my emmet

[image: my emmet]

my emmet border

[image: my emmet border]

the emmet abbreviation it should be

[image: the emmet abbreviation it should be]

Comment: what else do you expect to see if you type `.`?

Comment: I use Boostrap4 and there are many classes, usually when I type dot (.), several column options appear, but only 2 appear. oh ... yes, from the 2 column image, it can still be scrolled down.

and this not only affects the class but the location of the file selection also only displays 2 columns.

Comment: Bootstrap is not part of Emmet, where in the Emmet code do you find Bootstrap classes? Most likely they should come from a Bootstrap extension that has a completion provider. Your talking about `2 column` but I don't see this in the pictures

Comment: Not only in the class, even when I follow the image below when using border-radius it only displays 2 columns, even though there are still a lot of options for the border itself but from the 2 columns it can still be scrolled.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961740/836330 that may fix your issue.

Comment: that works, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Code intellisense showing one suggestion at any time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64789393/visual-studio-code-intellisense-showing-one-suggestion-at-any-time)

Just drag the bottom border for the emmet abbreviation suggestions drop box down.
The above link has a similar question with a much better and properly explained answer.

Comment: Yup it works, thanks